# ios uitableview bounce went wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I implemented a horizontal table view and it looks like this

[image]

The category bar, Dining Shopping something, is a horizontal table view and here is the implementation code.

```
LogInfo(@"Show Category Table start");
// add categories to be subview controller
self.categoriesTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.categoriesTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
[self.categoriesTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, SCREENWIDTH, 44)];
self.categoriesTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.categoriesTable.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.categoriesTable.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.categoriesTable.delegate = self;
self.categoriesTable.dataSource = self;
self.categoriesTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.superView addSubview:self.categoriesTable];
LogInfo(@"Show Category Table Finished");
self.categoriesTable.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
```

It works as expect but if I change view, for example, I click any button to go to other view and go back to this view. The tableview looks like this

[image]

This problem also happpens even if I disable the bounce effect of the table view. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In the above code there is no line written to disable the bounce effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than applying a transform to the table to make it horizontal, use a collectionView with a horizontal layout.

**Edit**: If you want to continue using your current setup, try disabling `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on your view controller.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

**Edit 2**: If you're curious, since iOS 7 every view controller looks at its topmost/first scroll view and adjusts its `contentInsets` to compensate for the navigation bar transparency which is enabled by default. In this case of course, such behaviour isn't desired at all.